# Bootstrap datepicker disable feature

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need in my project a feature I think bootstrap datepicker still doesn't offer. I'd like to enable/disable a datepicker field so a user can't be able to change its value. Something like a readOnly functionality.

Any ideas about it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can find it posted as an answer

Comment: If you verified the solution you should check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but just by modifying the bootstrap calendar code. Overriding the this._events part to disable keyup/down event worked for me:

```
_buildEvents: function(){
        if (this.isInput) { // single input
            this._events = [
                [this.element, {
                    focus: $.proxy(this.show, this),
                    keyup: $.proxy(this.update, this),
                    keydown: $.proxy(this.keydown, this)
                }]
            ];
        }
        else if (this.component && this.hasInput){ // component: input + button
            this._events = [
                // For components that are not readonly, allow keyboard nav
                [this.element.find('input'), {
                    //focus: $.proxy(this.show, this),
                    //keyup: $.proxy(this.update, this),
                    //keydown: $.proxy(this.keydown, this)
                }],
                [this.component, {
                    click: $.proxy(this.show, this)
                }]
            ];
        }
        else if (this.element.is('div')) {  // inline datepicker
            this.isInline = true;
        }
        else {
            this._events = [
                [this.element, {
                    click: $.proxy(this.show, this)
                }]
            ];
        }

        this._secondaryEvents = [
            [this.picker, {
                click: $.proxy(this.click, this)
            }],
            [$(window), {
                resize: $.proxy(this.place, this)
            }],
            [$(document), {
                mousedown: $.proxy(function (e) {
                    // Clicked outside the datepicker, hide it
                    if (!(
                        this.element.is(e.target) ||
                        this.element.find(e.target).length ||
                        this.picker.is(e.target) ||
                        this.picker.find(e.target).length
                    )) {
                        this.hide();
                    }
                }, this)
            }]
        ];
    },
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$("#nicIssuedDate").prop('disabled', true);
```

this works for me with  **Bootstrap Datepicker and Jquery**

Answer (score 4):

You can do following:

For disabling:

`$("#date").datepicker("option", "disabled", true);`

and for enabling:

`$("#date").datepicker("option", "disabled", false);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`onRender`**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) event of Bootstrap, which disables the **`datepicker`**.

> **`onRender`**:   This event is fired when a day is rendered inside the datepicker. Should return a string. Return 'disabled' to disable the
>   day from being selected.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$('#idOfYourCalendar').data("DateTimePicker").disable();
```

official docs:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the option enabledDates to an array of only the date you would like to show. Also set the date to that date. All other dates will then be disabled.

```
enabledDates: ['your_date_to_show'],
```

Eg.

```
  $('#Date').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    viewMode: "days",
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    enabledDates: [fetchDate("Date")],
  })
  .data("DateTimePicker")
  .date(fetchDate("Date"));

  $('#Date').ready(function (){
    $("#Date").data("DateTimePicker").date(fetchDate("Date"));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$("#nicIssuedDate").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get acceptable solution as follow:

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: moment(),
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }).end().on('keypress paste', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
```

Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score -6):

You just have to use jquery attr method

```
$('').attr('disabled', true);
```

Thats All :)