# How to disable/grey out Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have a dropdown menu with two values, I want to disable or grey out bootstrap datepickers when a particular value is chosen from the drop down.

Using Javascript or JQuery is there any way to disable or grey out a bootstrap datepicker so that a user cannot enter any value?

I have extensively researched this online and the suggested JQuery prop and atr methods have no effect.

I have attached an image of what the screen should ideally look like below:

[image: Desired behavior mock up]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datepicker disable feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569292/bootstrap-datepicker-disable-feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your drop down list has id ddlSelect and your calendar as inputCalendar

```
$("#ddlSelect").change(function(){
   var ddlValue = $("#ddlSelect option:selected").val();
   if(ddlValue == 'specific value'){
     $("#inputCalendar").prop('disabled', true);
   }
})
```

Comment: this is the solution I was trying before posting this question online. For some unknown reason .prop is having no effect. The field does not disable

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you mention you have tried it.
But can you try put your problem on service like jsfiddle or js bin. Because I tried it on js bin and it works.
check it out at : https://output.jsbin.com/ganeya/4

Comment: In the end your solution is valid I fixed my problem using:                                         $("#inputCalendar").attr('disabled', true);

Answer (score 0):

```
callback: {
                    message: 'The Message You want if',
                    callback: function(value, validator) {
                        var m = new moment(value, 'Condition you want', true);
                        if (!m.isValid()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return m.isAfter(globCommonVar.Your_value);
                    }
                }
```

May this work for u too ...... Bdw this part is in validator