# Disable input field with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html for my bootstrap datetimepicker. I want to disable the `<input>` and force the user to make use of the datetimepicker. I've tried using `disabled` and `readonly="readonly"` attribute. But after adding the attribute, my datetimepicker doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<div class='input-group date' id='startDate'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
 </div> 

 $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    useCurrent: true,
    viewMode: "days"
 });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569292/bootstrap-datepicker-disable-feature

Comment: What plugin are you using? Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hz6xuu0o/

Comment: I'm using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `disabled` attribute to your input like:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" name="startDate" disabled />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hz6xuu0o/

Comment: I've tried it. And it doesn't work on mine. I'll edited the question with my JS. If it helps.

Comment: Is working as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hz6xuu0o/1/ ? Can you provide a demo of the issue?

Comment: it's weird. when i put it into the fiddle it works. but it doesn't work on my .jsp

Comment: In this example you still can edit by clicking on calendar icon

Comment: When we make it disabled, we can't post the data. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get acceptable solution as follow:

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment(),
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}).on('keypress paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: Hi, I tried this but not work. But, I make separate section, an it works. I make it another $(".date") and I add the on event. Then it becoming like this 

$(".date").on('keypress paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

Answer (score 0):

Everything is rapped up in the input div so it's sees the datetimepicker as the input. So take the input div out or take the datetimepicker out