# bootstrap datetimepicker unable to disable onload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a `bootstrap datetimepicker` and a button:

When the page load the `datetimepicker` should be disabled. On clicking the button it should make enabled:

What I did as follows:

```
<div id="div_choose_date" style="display:block;margin-top:20px;">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px">
                            <span class="small">Date</span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="pickdate"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="showpicker">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>                                      
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" id="btn_changedate" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;">Change</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

For disabling I tried as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
                pickTime: false,
                format : "YYYY/MM/DD",
                startDate: new Date()
                }); 

                $("#div_choose_date").prop('disabled', true);

                $("#btn_changedate").click(function(){

                 $("#div_choose_date").prop('disabled', false);

            });
    });
```

But unfortunately it is not working!!

How can I disable datetimepicker onload and make it enable on button click?

Comment: This question was answered in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18569432/522814

Comment: Cant you do this way `$("#btn_changedate").click(function(){$("#div_choose_date").datetimepicker();});`

Comment: @SandeepNayak in my case I can able to select dates on page load, but it should be disabled!!

Answer (score -1):

Per your code, datepicker isn't even enabled to begin with. To do this you need to initialize the plugin,

```
$(function() {
    $('#pickdate').datetimepicker();    
});
```

If you want to disable (ie - destroy), then you can do as so:

```
$('#someButton').click(function(e) {
    $('#pickdate').datetimepicker('remove')  // or $('#element').datepicker('destroy');
});
```

You can view this on [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/723Lqurt/) - first enable it (click grn button), then click the other button. You'll notice that the date doesn't pop up anymore

Some people say that it's easier to just remove the element all together (as in some cases boostrap doesn't come w/ a `destroy` method). However, the function, `datetimepicker('remove')` does work. Therefore, since you said that your datepicker is actually **enabled** on load, which doesn't make sense but w/e, then go ahead and use the `datetimepicker('remove')`.

Comment: remove/destroy methods not working as expected!! it is `datetimepicker` not `datepicker`

Comment: funny for the downvote - datetimepicker has a `destroy` method. Read the docs. also prior to you downvoting you "edited 53 mins ago" your post. w/e